# Is Returning a value and also have an escaping parameter in the same function considered bad practice?

Tags: swift

Is this code considered bad practice?
Is there any benefit or downside to having both a return value and a completion handler in the same function?

For example:

```
func isPrintHelloWorld(status: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) -> Bool {
   print("hello world")

   completion(false)
   return false
}
```

Comment: Well there is no relation between the bool returned from your method and the bool returned on completion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of good or bad practice. If that is what you need, in order to accomplish or communicate what you need to accomplish or communicate, then that is what you need. If it isn't, it isn't.

Here's a well-known method that both returns a value and takes a completion handler, and both the returned value and the completion handler are of great importance:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask

But it's probably fair to say that situations demanding that sort of thing are few and far between.

Also, this pattern is a lot rarer in Swift than in Objective-C. For example, this method takes a completion handler and also returns a BOOL in Objective-C:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620747-performchangesandwait?language=objc

But the very same method, translated into Swift, doesn't return a value:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620747-performchangesandwait

That's because if there's an issue, Swift can throw instead.

So, regardless of goodness or badness of practice, I'd say, if you're thinking of returning a value while also taking a completion handler, think again; there may be a Swiftier way.